# Percentage and Sticky

Tags: php, loops, percentage, sticky

I'm working on this project and I keep running into some issues. First off, it's a quiz that needs to calculate the percentage correct and out put it (all the code will be at the end). The issue with it right now is that it's always calculating 0%, even with right answers and a variable is defined for it. My second issue is that it's not sticky and it needs to be. I don't know what's going on with that. I have only one line done right now and it's not sticky. Help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<?php
    $score = 0;
$percent = 0;

//checking submit button
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
}


//multi-dimensional arrays for questions, selections, and answers
$questions = array(
    'q1' => array('question' => 'Which is optional to making Easy Fudge?', 
        'choice 1' => 'Nuts', 
        'choice 2' => 'Condensed Milk', 
        'choice 3' => 'semi-sweet morsels', 
        'choice 4' => 'bakers chocolate <br />', 
        'answer' => 'nuts 
'),
        'q2' => array('question' => 'One square of bakers chocolate is optional to help enhance the flavor and texture?',
        'choice 1' => 'Yes',
        'choice 2' => 'No',
        'choice 3' => 'I do not know what this bakers chocolate is.',
        'choice 4' => 'Maybe. <br />',
        'answer' => 'Yes', ),
    'q3' => array('question' => 'Between prepration time, cooking time, and cooling time, how long does it take to make Easy Fudge?',
        'choice 1' => '130 minutes',
        'choice 2' => '131 minutes',
        'choice 3' => '132 minutes',
        'choice 4' => '133 minutes <br />',
        'answer' => '131 minutes',),
    'q4' => array('question' => 'If divided into 48 pieces, 2 pieces of this fudge is how many calories?',
        'choice 1' => '140 calories',
        'choice 2' => '150 calories',
        'choice 3' => '160 calories',
        'choice 4' => '170 calories <br />',
        'answer' => '160 calories'),
    'q5' => array('question' => 'You combine your morsels and sweetend condensed milk in a medium sauce pan over which heat?',
        'choice 1' => 'low',
        'choice 2' => 'medium-low',
        'choice 3' => 'medium',
        'choice 4' => 'high <br />',
        'answer' => 'low'),
        );

 //radio buttons and selectability
foreach($questions as $key => $question){
echo $question['question'] . '<br />';  

// TODO: check the POST value and compare to this value (ie. "one")
echo '<input type="radio" name = "'.$key.'" value="one"> '  . $question['choice 1'] . '<br />'; 
    //echo (isset($_POST['radio'] and $_POST['radio']== "one") )? "checked" : "";

echo '<input type="radio" name = "'.$key.'" value="two" >' . $question['choice 2'] . '<br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name = "'.$key.'" value="three"> ' . $question['choice 3'] . '<br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name = "'.$key.'" value="four"> ' . $question['choice 4'] . '<br />';

}


//looping through the questions with nested loops

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
foreach($questions as $key => $question){
    if ( $question['answer']== $_POST[$key]){
        $score++;   
    }else{ $score = $score;
    }
}echo $score;
}//= ($score/5)*100 . "%";

?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you debug your own script? Did you dump those arrays and the $_POST array to see what they contain? Because if not, I will vote to close this question.

Comment: With dumping I mean using `print_r($array)` to see what you're actually dealing with. Same for the $_POST superglobal array.

Comment: I mean with the radio buttons, making them stay selected after the form is submitted. I've been trying to do debugging but my issues keep being the same.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is here

```
echo '<input type="radio" name = "'.$key.'" value="one"> '  . $question['choice 1'] . '<br />';
```

(and on the other 3 lines like it).  The 'value' of the radio button is 'one', so, if it's selected, what's sent as a POST variable is q1=one.

Then, later on, you compare it on the line:

```
if ( $question['answer']== $_POST[$key]){
```

Which equates to:

```
if ( "nuts" = $_POST['q1'] )
```

We know $_POST['q1'] will be 'one', so therefore even if you selected the correct answer, it's never counted.

There are 2 ways to cure this

1. Change all your answers in the array to 'one', 'two', etc...
2. Change your radio button's value, outputting the $question['choice 1'] in there too

Hope that helps set you on the right path ;)

Comment: Looks like the author of this post took the answer and ran without rewarding any community effort :) Another homework assignment done successfully. As your answer is a little more descriptive and less "pissy" than mine, I'm upvoting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would expect "$question['answer']" (low) to match $_POST[$key] "one" ??

Not only is your processing logic incorrect (because you set the value of your radio buttons to "one", "two"... etc. But the logic you've used to create your radio buttons is incorrect.

Go back and print_r on your question array, then once you see what you're dealing with, figure out how you are going to loop it appropriately to build your radio buttons.

Next, you need to print_r on your $_POST data and see how THAT is being returned.

Here's a good start:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name = "'.$key.'" value="' . $question['choice 1'] . '"> '  . $question['choice 1'] . '<br />';
```